# ReloadData vs ReloadRowsAtIndexPaths (Specifically regarding Video Data from Files)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tableview

**Why does downloading video to a filepath require [tableview reloadData] in order to be seen on the tableview?**

I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days, and I am quite perplexed, and it's too bad the devforums are down.

Basically, I have a tableview. Each table view cell has a AVPlayer and a given remote URL. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, if the video data is not stored locally, it downloads it, and saves it to a file, and the AVPlayer attempts to play the video at the saved file location.

The problem is, that nothing ever gets played.

Unless I call `[tableView reloadData]` in each `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in order for the videos to be rendered. I realize that this may be quite bad for performance, as well as, not very nice for the user, so I try using the `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` for each cell, but that does not work.

**Why does my app need to call reloadData in order to load data from a given local file location? And why doesn't reloadRowsAtIndexPath work? What's the difference between the two, in terms of getting video data that has been recently written to a file path.**

I'd rather not reload anything, it's just the app is unaware of new data in a given file path if I do not reload the tableview.

---

Code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *const cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
        AVideoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self getURL:someURLString forIndexPath:indexPath] options:nil];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[AVideoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
            AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.player];
            cell.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
            layer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 179.0);
            [cell.layer addSublayer: layer];
        }
        else {
            [cell.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        }
        [cell.player play];

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code, in particular of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: @MrMage Updated question with the code

Comment: The reason this is happening is because the tableView dataSource has cached the URL value until that cell needs to be repopulated, by either scrolling off screen or force reloaded, and the one in memory is not the same as the one you get by downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an asynchronous/synchronous issue, I think.

I was using AFNetworking to download the file in the getURL method.

```
[operation waitUntilFinished]
```

^This fixed the issue. I guess, the entire file was not getting downloaded before the getURL method returned the local URL, so the Asset may have possibly been getting corrupted.

The only issue with this is, I am worried that for slow internet connections, the main thread may be blocked for too long. Each video is about 140KB.

**If you know, a better approach that will not block the main thread please let me know.**

Glad to have finally figured it out, after three stressful days. :)

Comment: Download the video asynchronously, then use e.g. dispatch_main to update the corresponding cell on the main queue when the download finishes. There are lots of examples for this (especially with image views) on the internet.

Comment: @MrMage I had tried this earlier with the URL, but I guess I should try this with AVPlayer/PlayerItem/Asset etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to play a video in each table cell? That's not going to work. Video playback is extremely resource intensive. Adding video layers to a table view cell each with its own player is a non-starter. It's hard enough for table views to perform well with still images if it's not done correctly. Displaying video in real time in a table cell is nigh impossible. You need to reconsider your approach to the design. Maybe just load the poster image for each video in the table cell and then do playback when the user taps on the cell?

If you insist on going this route so you can see for yourself, though, my guess is that you're probably not using the correct NSURL method to instantiate your file URL. Set a breakpoint at this line:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:
                      [self getURL:someURLString forIndexPath:indexPath] 
                                        options:nil];
```

Then step over that line and then hover your mouse over the asset variable. If it's nil, something is wrong with your NSURL that you're instantiating in your `getURL:forIndexPath:` method.

Make sure you're using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` to load it from disk. iOS makes a distinction between file URLs and web URLs. Also make sure your file actually exists at the file URL you're using.

Comment: The NSURL is not nil, my videos are on average about 140KB (2-3 seconds on repeat), I thought that it works for Vine, so why can't I try (with shorter videos than Vine), yes I am using fileURLWithPath, the file does exist at the URL I am using, the asset, player item, and player all exist (none of them are nil, although AVPlayItemStatus is unknown for some reason), they just don't play. I do appreciate the long answer though, thanks for your help. :) @MattLong

Comment: Check my answer to see what the problem was (it was in code not displayed above). @MattLong